# MySQL Automatic UPDATE COLUMN

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, automatic-updates

Everyday I need to UPDATE a column automatically:

```
update client_invoices set x6 = datediff(x4, date_due)
```

Im using an event in mysql but everytime the hosting company updates the server the `Event scheduler status` is turned off.

Any way I can perform this without scheduling events?

Comment: You can create an application code, and let a Cron run that code daily.

Comment: Hi Madhur, what kind of code?